# Grafana - Graph with metrics on demand

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana for my application, where I have metrics being exposed from my data source on demand, and I want to monitor such on-demand metrics in Grafana in a user-friendly graph. For example, until an exception has been hit by my application, the data source does NOT expose the metric named 'Exception'. However, I want to create a graph before hand where I should be able to specify the metric 'Exception' and it should log it in the graph whenever my data source exposes the 'Exception' metric.

When I try to create a graph on Grafana using the web GUI, I'm unable to see these 'on-demand metrics' since they've not yet been exposed by my data source. However, I should be able to configure the graph such that in case these metrics are exposed then show them. If I go ahead and type out the non-exposed metric name in the metrics field, I get an error "Timeseries data request error".

Does Grafana provide a method to do this? If so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what data source you are using (Graphite, InfluxDB, OpenTSDB?).

For graphite you can enter raw query mode (pen button). To specify what ever query you want, it does not need to exist. Same is true InfluxDB, you find the raw query mode in the hamburger menu drop down to the right of eacy query.

You can also use wildcards in a graphite query (or regex in InfluxDB) to create generic graphs that will add series to the graph as they come in.

Comment: My datasource is JmxReporter, where we expose the metrics on the JMX port. Is there a similar option in JmxReporter?

Comment: We also tried to connect Grafana to Zabbix as data source, it works perfectly!